# Android mysql connectivity

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an app for android which connects to external MySQL database via a php script to get data. The problem is that the amount of data is too large and I am running into outofmemoryexception when trying to load the data. I used pagination approach showing 10 items at a time - when the user scrolls to the bottom of listview next 10 items are shown. The problem here is that the loading is very slow. I need to make the app responsive. What is the approach that I should use? The code I used is as follows -

```
public class ItemActivity extends Activity {

    private String str = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode
        // is
        // most
        // commonly
        // used
        // to
        // catch
        // accidental
        // disk
        // or
        // network
        // access
        // on
        // the
        // application's
        // main
        // thread
        .penaltyLog().build());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);
        setTitle("Kurd Shopping");

        final int id=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",String.valueOf(id)));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startid", "0"));
            str=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://kurdshopping.net/apj/adlist.php", postParameters);
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(str);
            final Item[] item_data=new Item[array.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<item_data.length;i++){
                JSONObject jdata=array.getJSONObject(i);
                String path="http://kurdshopping.net/thumbs/"+jdata.getString("name");
                item_data[i]=new Item(jdata.getInt("id"), path, jdata.getString("title")+"\nPrice: "+jdata.getString("price"));
            }
            final ItemAdapter adapter=new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, item_data);
            final ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(ItemActivity.this, item_data[position].id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    int lastVisibleitem=firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount;
                    if(lastVisibleitem==totalItemCount){
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",String.valueOf(id)));
                        String s=String.valueOf(item_data[lastVisibleitem-1].id);
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startid", s));
                        try {
                            str=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://kurdshopping.net/apj/adlist.php", postParameters);
                            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(str);
                            for(int i=0;i<item_data.length;i++){
                                JSONObject jdata=array.getJSONObject(i);
                                String path="http://kurdshopping.net/thumbs/"+jdata.getString("name");
                                item_data[i]=new Item(jdata.getInt("id"), path, jdata.getString("title")+"\nPrice: "+jdata.getString("price"));
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listView.setSelection(0);
                        }catch(JSONException j){
                            Log.e("ItemActivity", j.getMessage());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else if(lastVisibleitem==totalItemCount){

                    }
                }
            });
        }catch(NotFoundException n){
            Log.e("ItemActivity", n.getMessage());
        }catch(JSONException j){
            Log.e("ItemActivity", j.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ItemActivity", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

any help or advise will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide code snippets to illustrate the point?

Comment: google once lazy loading in android